# Overwriting SQLite Database on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a database.sqlite file, I used `NSlog` to know where is the file located, hopefully I got the location

and the question is, I want to overwrite that database with a button, so when ever the user click the button, it overwrites the database, but instead of overwriting, it saves the database to the following path

> /Users/MYUsername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4453818A-0617-479B-B98C-3FC544A24D00/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F15404E8-AB5B-40D6-A4D5-ED42F8F7A682/Documents/Database.sqlite

which is not what I want, I want to save the database to here

> /Users/MYUsername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4453818A-0617-479B-B98C-3FC544A24D00/data/Containers/Data/Application/BD3E2250-DF45-480F-AB06-F8E97D3B0B37/Documents

I tried the following code:

```
- (IBAction)updateDatabase:(id)sender {

    NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file URL"]];

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  executablePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

    [dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"File Not exsists : %@",filePath);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File exsits : %@",filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: each application is identified by a UUID(universally unique identifier) because the UUIDs are different this means there are two applications

Comment: @MohammadAlavi, there is one application, the dictionary is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you run your application a new UUID is created and the files are copied to this new directory to verify this add the following code in your  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
NSLog(@"executablePath: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]);

NSURL *urlDocument = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *pathDatabase = [[urlDocument path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

BOOL databaseExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathDatabase];
NSLog(@"databaseExists: %@", databaseExists ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

by the way you should check if the file exists at `filePath` before writing the database content (`dbFile`) to the file at this location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use:

```
[[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject] path]
```

instead of

```
[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
```

See Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407726-urlsfordirectory?language=objc

*(edited)*

Like so:

```
- (IBAction)updateDatabase:(id)sender {

    NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file URL"]];

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject] path]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];

    [dbFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"File Not exsists : %@",filePath);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File exsits : %@",filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i am new to programming, you mean like that? `NSString*string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[manager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]];`